# Windows Phone map.setView() in portrait mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a route displayed on a map in my Windows Phone. Now I want to fit the zoom based on the route which is drawn on the map.

I did the following:

```
this.map.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(locations));
```

`locations` is an array of `GeoCoordinate`s. In landscape orientation it works perfectly, but when I switch to portrait orientation it doesn`t.

---EDIT---

Here is the relevant code:

In my draw method, which is called in my OnLoad-Method, my locations array gets filled here:

```
double[,] givenCoordinates;
private MapOverlay overlay;
private Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer layer = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer();
private List<GeoCoordinate> locations = new List<GeoCoordinate>();

private void drawMap()
{
    try
    {
        bool centerPosition = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenCoordinates.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            GeoCoordinate tmpCoord;
            GeoCoordinate centerPoint = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0);

            Image image = new Image();
            BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\pushpin.png", UriKind.Relative));
            image.Width = 40;
            image.Height = 40;
            image.Opacity = 10;
            image.Source = myImage;

            if (givenCoordinates[i, 0] != 0 && givenCoordinates[i, 1] != 0)
            {
                tmpCoord = new GeoCoordinate(givenCoordinates[i, 0], givenCoordinates[i, 1]);

                if (!centerPosition)
                {
                    centerPoint = new GeoCoordinate(givenCoordinates[i, 0], givenCoordinates[i, 1]);
                    centerPosition = true;
                }

                overlay = new MapOverlay
                {
                    GeoCoordinate = tmpCoord,
                    Content = image,
                    PositionOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0.5, 1)
                };
                layer.Add(overlay);
                locations.Add(tmpCoord);
            }
        }
        delMap.Layers.Add(layer);

        Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline line = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading the map!");
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I call the setView() Method in my OrientationChanged event, in the Loaded event and after a button click, so you can easily restore zoom to default.
Code:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.delMap.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(locations));
}

private void btn_default_zoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{
    this.delMap.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(locations));
}
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged_1(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
     delMap.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(locations));
}
```

All of this works fine in landscape mode, none of them work in portrait mode, not even the button click.

Comment: Try to call UpdateLayout after or before

Comment: this isn`t working for me

Comment: Can you post your code so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I edited my post, I think i filtered out the relevant things :)

Comment: It works for me in both orientations, it doesn't go straight to that position at start. I had to put a thread.sleep between drapmap and map.SetView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with this little change on when calling the drawMap

```
//just for testing a list of locations
givenCoordinates = new double[3, 2];
givenCoordinates[0, 0] = 23.4896;
givenCoordinates[0, 1] = 12.1392;
givenCoordinates[1, 0] = 23.4835;
givenCoordinates[1, 1] = 12.1794;
givenCoordinates[2, 0] = 23.5153;
givenCoordinates[2, 1] = 12.1516;



drawMap();

await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        delMap.SetView(LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(locations), MapAnimationKind.Linear);
    });
});
```

Comment: it`s funny because its not working in my case ... if I click the button in Portrait-Mode, nothing happens, no error, no wrong positioning, just nothing ... weird :/

Comment: no, it doesn`t work with any of these, neither in loaded, nor in orientation changed

Comment: What is your expected behavior? Because maybe i'm getting a different behavior from what you expect.
I get the mapp centered and zoomed on the locations passed to the SetView

Comment: yeah i get the same in landscape mode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51415/discussion-between-verdesrobert-and-crusader633)

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems to happen just on my phone. The other employees had no problem when they tested it on their testphones. I will accept your answer, because you helped me to fix the bug with the Loaded event, thanks :)